# Can you get enter two functions or values in Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

Sorry if the question is confusing or stupid but basically in a sorted function I want Lambda to check the names and if they both have the same name check to see which house comes for example

```
def get_name(list):
    return list['Names'], list['House']
```

would check the name then the house they're in can lambda do the same or just take one parameter

```
for student in sorted(students, key=lambda studen: studen['Names']):
    print(f"{student['Names']} is in {student['House']}")
```

My question is: how to write Lambda that equals to the `get_name()` function?

Comment: I'm sorry, **what is your question?**

Comment: Are you asking how to create a lambda expression which results in a function equivalent to the `get_name` function you have already written?

Comment: Yes how to write Lambda that equals the get_name function

Comment: Here's a hint: a lambda expression `lambda <args>: <expression>` is exactly equivalent to `def _f(<args>): return <expression>`. of course, no name `_f` is created. Note, you **don't ever really require a lambda expression**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply have your lambda return a tuple:

```
sorted(students, key=lambda student: (student['Names'], student['House']))
```

---

Or alternatively, using the `get_name` function that you defined:

```
sorted(students, key=get_name)
```

Comment: Or using `operator.itemgetter`: `sorted(students, key=itemgetter('Names', 'House'))`

Answer (score -1):

```
students = [
    {'Names': 'Alice', 'House': 'Gryffindor'},
    {'Names': 'Bob', 'House': 'Hufflepuff'},
    {'Names': 'Alice', 'House': 'Ravenclaw'},
    {'Names': 'Charlie', 'House': 'Slytherin'},
    {'Names': 'Eve', 'House': 'Gryffindor'}
]

for student in sorted(students, key=lambda student: (student['Names'], student['House'])):
    print(f"{student['Names']} is in {student['House']}")
```

Try the code above.

The lambda function used as the `key` parameter returns a tuple `(student['Names'], student['House'])` for each student. When the sorted function compares two students, it will first compare their names, and if the names are the same, it will then compare their houses. This achieves the desired sorting behavior where students with the same name are sorted by their houses.

Comment: As you have demonstrated input, it would be better to show the output, rather than to simply say "try this."